# When using infile in SAS for a fixed-width file, how do you stop input when you encounter a blank line?

Tags: file-io, sas

Imagine you have a particular fixed-width file with lines of data you are interested in, a few blank lines, and then a bunch of data and descriptions that you are not interested in. How do you read in that file but stop at the blank line?

For example, if you download and unzip the following document:

http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_Factors_TXT.zip

And attempt to read in the data in SAS like so

```
data FF;
    infile 'C:/Data/F-F_Research_Data_Factors.txt' firstobs=5 stopover;
    input date Mkt_RF SMB HML RF;
run;
```

It reads in "extra" lines near the bottom that are not monthly data but are instead annual data. Is there a way to stop at the blank line?

Comment: It's better to include a few lines of sample input data in your question rather than link to a file. When asking for help, you want to make it as easy as possible for people to help you. Many folks won't download external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple file like the example just use a conditional `STOP` statement.  Also note that you can read those YYYYMM values as actual date values instead of treating them as just numbers.

```
data FF;
  infile 'C:/Data/F-F_Research_Data_Factors.txt' firstobs=5 truncover;
  input date Mkt_RF SMB HML RF;
  informat date yymmn6.;
  format date yymmn6.;
  if date=. then stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is untested, but should do what you are looking to achieve.

```
DATA FF;
INFILE 'C:/F-F_RESEARCH_DATA_FACTORS.TXT' FIRSTOBS=5 TERMSTR = CRLF;

/*READ IN ONLY VARIABLE DATE AND EVALUATE CONTENTS.*/

INPUT DATE @;

/*IF THERE IS A BLANK LINE THEN STOP READING IN THE FILE*/

IF DATE = . THEN STOP;

/*IF THE VALUE IS NOT MISSING THEN READ IN THE REMAINING COLUMNS*/

ELSE INPUT MKT_RF SMB HML RF;

RUN;
```

Comment: I should mention that the @@ stops the cursor from progressing to the next column, so that a condition can be tested and then continues when the next INPUT is encountered.

Comment: I think maybe you want just a single trailing @.  So that the pointer will go to the next row after each iteration of the data step.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you test each row before you attempt to parse the row using something like the following.

```
data FF;
    infile 'C:/Data/F-F_Research_Data_Factors.txt' firstobs=5 stopover;
    input @;
    if _infile_='' then stop;
    input @1 date Mkt_RF SMB HML RF;
run;
```

The `input @;` statement reads in the entire line but doesn't release the line due to the trailing `@`. The `_infile_` variable is automatically loaded with the entire line by the input statement. We then test the line for being blank. The original input statement then needs `@1` to reset the line read pointer to the first column so it can function normally.